# Resampling gap between Datetime filling with previous values (multi-index)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to correct every row that there is no date. Then idea is just to fill the gap between the missing dates, and complete the other columns with the previous values.

```
        ds            SKU  Estoque leadtime
0   2018-01-02  504777  45  11
1   2018-01-04  504777  42  11
2   2018-01-05  504777  41  11
3   2018-01-09  504777  40  11
4   2018-01-12  504777  37  11
5   2018-01-13  504777  36  11
6   2018-01-15  504777  35  11
... ... ... ... ...
6629    2018-08-14  857122  11  10
6630    2018-08-15  857122  10  10
6631    2018-08-16  857122  9   10
6632    2018-08-17  857122  7   10
6633    2018-08-23  857122  14  10
6634    2018-08-24  857122  13  10
```

I have already tried to:

```
df.set_index('ds', inplace=True)
df = df.resample("D")
```

or

```
df.resample("D", how='first', fill_method='ffill')
```

But I just got this:

```
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Day>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

When I tried :

```
(df.groupby('SKU')
 .resample('D')
 .last()
 .reset_index()
 .set_index('ds'))
```

I got this error :

```
ValueError: cannot insert SKU, already exists
```

I am trying to have this result:

```
        ds            SKU  Estoque leadtime
0   2018-01-02  504777  45  11
1   2018-01-03  504777  45  11
2   2018-01-04  504777  42  11
3   2018-01-05  504777  41  11
4   2018-01-06  504777  41  11
5   2018-01-07  504777  41  11
6   2018-01-08  504777  41  11
7   2018-01-09  504777  40  11
... ... ... ... ...
```

PS: If I set date as index, I have duplicated index. I need to isolate each product first (group by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you may need to chain with `apply`

```
#df.set_index('ds', inplace=True)

df.groupby('SKU').apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: when try this, I got `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit` if I set `ds` as a index

Comment: This error is related to duplicated index. Because I have different products (SKU) for the same date (as index). Is it possible to apply this using multi index (SKU + date) ?